# Google Cloud SQL using more storage than needed

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I've recently moved some MySQL hosting from a virtual server at Digital Ocean to Google's Cloud SQL hosting. It took several goes to import the database and I didn't notice until afterwards that each time I deleted a database in the Google console it didn't actually reset the storage space that database had used.

I've not got about 40GB of storage but I know the database is only about 10, is there some way to clear the space or do I need to start again and import the database into a fresh db setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data written to the disk is fragmented it is [not possible to reduce the size of the Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#changetiers) without directly affecting your data. This process would require careful defragmentation to ensure that the space being removed does not contain any of your data.

It is therefore recommended to turn off the [Automatic storage increase](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#automatic-storage-increase-2ndgen) setting for your instance, or set a limit on the size it is allowed to increase to in order to control the size of your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, strangely though the space being used dropped back down to a sensible level after a couple of weeks... no idea how or why!